# jQuery Skip and Take functions with JSON and .NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, pagination

I am trying to have a previous and next button for a list if items that is populated from JSON object in the Controller.

I have a skip and take variable so that I can do likewise with sets of records.  I want to paginate advancing 7 at a time (next), and reversing 7 at a time (previous).

The orders are being loaded properly, but I so not fully understand the skip take ideas, along with changing the CSS class when there are no more "pages" to render.

```
        var skip = 0;
    var take = 7;

    function loadItems() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAllItems")',
            data:
            {
                skip: skip,
                take: take
            },
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            success: function (items) {
                $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                    $('#ul-items').append('<li><a class="link">' + item.Information + '</a></li>');
                });
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#previous').live("click", function () {
            //page number , # of records needed
            skip(0);
            take(-7);

            if (i) {//execute if there are no previous selections available
                $('#previous').removeClass('enabled').addClass('disabled');
            }
        });

        $('#next').live("click", function () {
            //page number , # of records needed
            skip(1);
            take(7);

            if (i) {//execute if there are no previous selections available
                $('#next').removeClass('enabled').addClass('disabled');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be more like this, ypu don't have to change the take value, only the skip :

```
 $('#previous').live("click", function () {
            if (skip > 0) {
                skip = skip - 1;
            } else {
                $('#previous').removeClass('enabled').addClass('disabled');
            }
            loadItems();
        });

        $('#next').live("click", function () {
            skip = skip + 1;
            loadItems();
            $('#previous').addClass('enabled').removeClass('disabled');
        });
```

Comment: also on success of loadItems, you should check if you receive the max items (take = 7 so 7) and if not you should hide the next button.

Answer (score 1):

`Skip` allows you to well skip a number of items in the list. And `Take` well take the next number of items in the list.

Say you have a PaginatedList with 100 items and you want 10 items at a time.

Initially you take 10. 
The 2nd link will need to  skip 10 elements and take the next 10 elements.

So it will be something like `paginatedList.Skip(i*10).Take(10)` i will be your page number.

So if i was 0, 0*10 will be page 0 (actually is first page, but the user doesn't know that). 
`Take 10` will return the first 10 items.

Comment: So, how would that code look for the previous and next buttons; reversing 7 and taking 7?

Comment: You C# code you usually does the work. 
Say you are on link 6 and you want to see link 5. You will send your 5 to your Controller. paginatedList.Skip(4*10).Take(10) So you skip 40 items and take the next 10. That's just an idea :)